# Some users not able to approve request actions via outlook sent by power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, outlook, approval-process

I have written a flow that sends emails to users for approval but the keep getting these errors below and the submit/approve button doesn't work
Any ideas why this is happening
Thanks in Advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this article from Microsoft. Basically they said the solution is to use outlook web. Which I tried and it worked. Also, possibility of checking your filtering options from your network team. See article 2.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/issues-with-flow-approval-emails-in-outlook

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Actionable-Messages-from-Flow-Approval-not-working-in-Outlook/td-p/84769